# Elasticsearch logs missing cluster name

Tags: elasticsearch

We're on Elasticsearch 8.4.1 and redirect logs to fluentd for further ingestion to Elasticsearch, Loki, etc.

The issue is that our logs now do not have a cluster name, it just has a log4j template that renders itself.

```json
{
  "type": "server",
  "timestamp": "2022-11-03T17:01:55,646Z",
  "level": "INFO",
  "component": "o.e.m.j.JvmGcMonitorService",
  "cluster.name": "${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}",
  "node.name": "elasticsearch-node-name",
  "message": "[gc][3214543] overhead, spent [262ms] collecting in the last [1s]",
  "cluster.uuid": "OXO7uN4aS3WtVKY05y1VTw",
  "node.id": "7KIL_dYVQxSHMeA0sgZg6g"
}
```

Notice the `"${sys:es.logs.cluster_name}"` part, this is where I'd expect a cluster name to be instead of the stringified template.

This is a production cluster, it obviously has a name. I've also checked nodes settings - they contain a cluster name.

What could be the issue?

Comment: We have the same issue on 8.5.1 atm.